# How can I generate a random number with restrictions?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I generate a random number and restrict it within a range? `iagegrp` gives age bounds, `age02` gives point values. I can generate a random variable within each bound but I'd like to also restrict the age difference between the two variables to no more than 15. How can I do so?

```
dput(data)
        structure(list(iagegrp = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
        4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), labels = c(`No answer/refused` = -9, 
        `Don't know` = -8, `Interview not achieved` = -7, `Schedule not applicable` = -2, 
        `Item not applicable` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
        "double")), age02 = structure(c(72, 66, 34, 37, 50, 38, 62, 49, 
        36, 48, 75, 48, 75, 45, 34, 27, 39, 44, 54, 33), labels = c(`No answer/refused` = -9, 
        `Don't know` = -8, `Interview not achieved` = -7, `Schedule not applicable` = -2, 
        `Item not applicable` = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
        "double"))), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

To generate a random number for `iagegrp`,

```
set.seed(1)    
mutate(age = ifelse(iagegrp == 3, sample(25:44, 7, replace = TRUE), sample(45:64, 13, replace = TRUE))))
```

What can I do to restrict an age difference of 15 between `iagegrp` and `age02`. An example of what I want to achieve,

```
| iagegrp | age02 |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 62    | 72            |
| 64   | 66            |
| 45    | 34            |
| 45   | 37            |
```

Comment: Am I following this correctly? If `age02 == 72` and `iagegrp == 4` then `age` is a value from `45:64` that is no more than `72 ± 15`? What if the range set by `iagegrp` is more than 15 away from `age02`?

Comment: @Seth Yes. If it is more than 15 then i'd like to put NA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I got your question, feel free to clarify. But from what I got, if `iagegrp` is 3, then you want an age between 25 and 44 and if it is 4, between 45 and 64. But you also want to enforce a difference of 15 years maximum with your other variable `age02`, so in some cases the bounds will be more restricted. Here is my attempt to answer:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)  

# Create sample data
iagegrp <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
age02 <- c(72, 66, 34, 37, 50, 38, 62, 49, 36, 48, 75, 48, 75, 45, 34, 27, 39, 44, 54, 33)
df <- data.frame(iagegrp, age02)

df <- df |> 
  # Get bounds given by iagegrp
  mutate(iagegrp_min = ifelse(iagegrp == 3, 25, 45),
         iagegrp_max = ifelse(iagegrp == 3, 44, 64)) |> 
  # Get bounds given by age02
  mutate(age02_min = age02 - 15,
         age02_max = age02 + 15) |> 
  # Get actual bounds
  rowwise() |> # necessary to define custom bounds for each row
  mutate(age_min = max(iagegrp_min, age02_min),
         age_max = min(iagegrp_max, age02_max)) |> 
  # Sample between bounds
  mutate(age = sample(age_min:age_max, size = 1))
```

It creates a lot of intermediate columns that you can delete afterwards with `df |> select(iagegrp, age02, age)`.

Also, I could not reproduce the dataset with the code you provided, so I defined `df` in a custom way above.

Comment: In the #Get actual bounds step, is it possible to set the age_min and age_max to be the min and max of each row instead of the min and max of the column? Because now i'm getting an entire column of age_min of 12 and age_max of 90 @lisa

Comment: iagegrp   age02     iagegrp_min iagegrp_max age02_min age02_max age_min age_max   age
   <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1 4         72                 45          64        57        87      12      90    64
 2 4         66                 45          64        51        81      12      90    18

Comment: @Victoria oops my bad, I should have placed rowwise() before the "get actual bounds" step. The edited code should work now!

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` approach, using `case_when` to establish each row's range.

```r
library(dplyr)                                              

df %>%
  mutate(
    age_lb = case_when(
      iagegrp == 3 ~ case_when(
        age02 < 25 & age02 >= 10 ~ 25,
        age02 - 25 > 15 ~ age02 - 15,
        age02 - 25 <= 15 ~ 25,
        TRUE ~ NA
      ),
      iagegrp == 4 ~ case_when(
        age02 < 45 & age02 >= 30 ~ 45,
        age02 - 45 > 15 ~ age02 - 15,
        age02 - 45 <= 15 ~ 45,
        TRUE ~ NA
      )
    ),
    age_ub = case_when(
      iagegrp == 3 ~ case_when(
        age02 > 44 & age02 <= 59 ~ 44,
        44 - age02 > 15 ~ age02 + 15,
        44 - age02 <= 15 ~ 44,
        TRUE ~ NA
      ),
      iagegrp == 4 ~ case_when(
        age02 > 64 & age02 <= 79 ~ 64,
        64 - age02 > 15 ~ age02 + 15,
        64 - age02 <= 15 ~ 64,
        TRUE ~ NA
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(age = sample(age_lb:age_ub, 1))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>    iagegrp age02 age_lb age_ub   age
#>      <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#>  1       4    72     57     64    59
#>  2       4    66     51     64    51
#>  3       4    34     45     49    48
#>  4       4    37     45     52    46
#>  5       4    50     45     64    55
#>  6       4    38     45     53    45
#>  7       4    62     47     64    50
#>  8       4    49     45     64    52
#>  9       4    36     45     51    51
#> 10       4    48     45     63    46
#> 11       4    75     60     64    61
#> 12       4    48     45     63    61
#> 13       4    75     60     64    61
#> 14       3    45     30     44    30
#> 15       3    34     25     44    32
#> 16       3    27     25     42    27
#> 17       3    39     25     44    37
#> 18       3    44     29     44    37
#> 19       3    54     39     44    40
#> 20       3    33     25     44    39
```